# Run a Azure Devops Job based on the outpu of python function

Tags: azure-pipelines

How do I configure a Azure Dev Ops job in my yaml file to trigger based on the output of a python function returning true/false?
Here is the job:

```
  - job: signature_qa
    dependsOn: verify
    displayName: "Quality approval by QA manager"
    pool: server
    timeoutInMinutes: 43200 # 30 days
    steps:
      - task: ManualValidation@0
        inputs:
          instructions: "Confirm that the QA processes has been followed"
          timeoutInMinutes: 43200 # 30 days
```

Comment: Please share the sample YAML you have so we can better understand the use case.

Comment: - job: signature_qa
    dependsOn: verify
    displayName: "Quality approval by QA manager"
    pool: server
    timeoutInMinutes: 43200 # 30 days
    steps:
      - task: ManualValidation@0
        inputs:
          instructions: "Confirm that the QA processes has been followed"
          timeoutInMinutes: 43200 # 30 days

Comment: Above is the job I want to run only when the python function returns "True" as output.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76431221/edit) your question and add all the details, code isn't readable in the comments.

Comment: Done, updated the question with the Yaml job